# Importing many python files from a seperate folder into a single other python file

Tags: python, file, import

### Files folder containing levels

[image]

### the import lines

[image]

As shown in the second image, in order to import 'level_one', python wanted me to create its own import line,
I tried to import both levels: level_one and level_two, by using the * symbol, which is what you would do to import all methods in a library (I believe this is how it works)
But that doesn't work. The picture below shows me attempting to call out a dictionary I have written in the 'level_two.py' file, but I would need another import statement to make it work.

### Where the file is called

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: [Please use text instead of images where possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: the title of your post shows a possible misunderstanding ... the python files are not imported into another file ... they are imported into the python interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're missing an `__init__.py` file. [You need one in the directory to make python treat the folder as a package.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)